# Can't call a method from a module built in Python C API

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I'm trying to build a python module in C++ using the Python C API and here is the code:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {};

    static MyClass& getInstance() {
        static MyClass instance;
        return instance;
    }

    void tester() {
        std::cout << "testing..." << std::endl;
    }

    static void runTesterFunc(PyObject*, PyObject*) {
        static MyClass& myObj = MyClass::getInstance();
        myObj.tester();
    }

    static PyObject* getModule() { 
        Py_SetPythonHome(L"C:\\Python36");
        Py_SetProgramName(L"my_program");

        PyMethodDef pyModuleMethods[] = {
            { "runTester", (PyCFunction)runTesterFunc, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "Foo Boo." },
            { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
        };

        static PyModuleDef MyModule = {
            PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
            "my_module",
            "Foo Boo.",
            -1,
            pyModuleMethods,
            NULL
        };

        return PyModule_Create(&MyModule);
    }

    void initializePython() {
        PyImport_AppendInittab("my_module", getModule);
        Py_Initialize();
    }

};

int main() {
    static MyClass& myObj = MyClass::getInstance();
    myObj.initializePython();
    PyRun_SimpleString(
        "import my_module \n"
        "my_module.runTester() \n"
    );
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when I run `my_module.runTester()` in `PyRun_SimpleString`. I get the following error message:

> SystemError: Bad call flags in PyCFunction_Call. METH_OLDARGS is no
>   longer supported!

I'm not using `METH_OLDARGS`. As you can see, I'm using `METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS`. What I could be missing here?

I'm using Python 3.6 and Windows 7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following modifications solved the problem:

```
static PyMethodDef pyModuleMethods[] = {
    { "runTester", (PyCFunction)runTesterFunc, METH_VARARGS | METH_KEYWORDS, "Foo Boo." },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

static struct PyModuleDef MyModule = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "my_module",
    "Foo Boo.",
    -1,
    pyModuleMethods,
    NULL
};
```